# Is there a tsconfig.json property that lets me type check a file but exclude it from being emitted as JavaScript?

Tags: typescript, tsconfig

I feel like the answer to my question should be in [the tsconfig reference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#Emit_6246), but I'm not finding a property for this.

I have a typescript project with many files. Some of them are `*.test.ts` files. These are tests and it is important to me that they are type checked, but I don't want them to be included in the final output (`"outFile": "./dist/output.js"`).

I know the directory structure is relevant to answering this question, but I actually have two projects with different directory structures and I want to know how to do this with both:

1. One project has separate `/src` and `/test` directories. Their parent directory is the project root.
2. In the other, source and test files share the same root and are intermingled in the same folders.

Normally I would use some external tool to remove/ignore certain emitted file**s** before concatenating them together, but in this case I'd like to use `outFile` which generates a single output file, therefore, there is no opportunity to use one of these tools.

Is there any way to configure these projects to type check certain files but emit a subset?

Comment: You may have 2 tsconfigs, one including them and one excluding them

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When is tsconfig.vitest.json used in a default vue@3 project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74055749/when-is-tsconfig-vitest-json-used-in-a-default-vue3-project)

Comment: @Dimava That doesn't seem like a duplicate to me. At a conceptual level, I may be able to answer my question with an npm script passing in commandline options to tsc like in that question. Other than that, I don't see the relation. It also doesn't say whether this can be done with a tsconfig property.